# Building a spatio-temporal filter

Tags: image-processing, convolution

I want to implement a spatio-temporal filter for my images which are a set of silhouettes of a cycle of walking. So I gather all the images in an array and convolve the 3D array with my spatio-temporal kernel, I mentioned below.
[image]

but my result is'nt correct. Here is my code please tell me what is my mistake.

```
import cv2,numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from PIL import Image
from scipy import ndimage


def gkern(l,sig):
    """\
    creates gaussian kernel with side length l and a sigma of sig
    """

    ax = np.linspace(-(l - 1) / 2., (l - 1) / 2., l)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(ax, ax)

    kernel = np.exp(-0.5 * (np.square(xx) +  np.square(yy)) / np.square(sig))

    return kernel / np.sum(kernel)

t = np.linspace(0,20,23)

h1 = np.array(gkern(5,5))[None,:,:]
h2= np.array(np.sinc(t-2))[:,None,None]

img_array=[]


for filename in glob.glob('t/*.bmp'):
    img = np.array(Image.open(filename).convert('I;16'))
    img_array.append(img)

v = np.array(img_array)

def fft(array):
  fft = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.fftn(np.fft.fftshift(array)))
  return fft

def ifft(array):
  ifft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifftn(np.fft.ifftshift(array)))
  return ifft

def conv_3D(array, kernel):
  conv = np.abs(ifft(fft(array)*fft(kernel)))
  return conv

st_kernel = conv_3D(h1, h2)
f_kernel = ndimage.convolve(v,st_kernel)

plt.figure(0)
plt.imshow(f[0,:,:],cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! As Brale said, this question seems to be more appropriate for SP SE. Also, programming issues are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate it to SP SE.

Comment: Can you talk about the problem a little bit more? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @A_A . I'm trying to build a spatio-temporal filter for gait recognition. the filter is called GSTI and what I've done is the first step of the algorithm taking the spatial and temporal features with 2 seperable filters that I mentioned above. I'm  affraid that my code does'nt implement the filter correctly and I don't know which part of it is wrong. here is the link of the full article:https://freepaper.me/leecher/pdf/10.1007/s11760-018-1326-5